# defrecord with empty constructor

Tags: clojure

I am using defrecord on a simple example, say:

```
 (defrecord Person [fname lname address])
```

I am using a tool that requires a 0-params constructor, so trying to use the above on the JVM leads to:

```
 CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
   Couldn't find 0-params constructor for class: 
       class user.Hello, compiling:(form-init5503453667732926891.clj:1:13)
```

What's the quickest/most beautiful way to get that 0-param constructor generated ?

Answer (score 0):

You should think of this record as of this class:

```
class Person {
    final Object fname;
    final Object lname;
    final Object address;

    public Person(final Object fname, final Object lname, final Object address) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

It is immutable, with all fields final etc.

Have a look at this [flowchart for choosing the right Clojure type definition form](http://cemerick.com/2011/07/05/flowchart-for-choosing-the-right-clojure-type-definition-form/).